# Organic Group OG membership relationships

Tags: 7, organic-groups, views

I'm trying to display on a views, only the nodes which the user is part of the Organic group.

I have a field og_group_ref in my content type which relate to a group.

What I want is for each user, display only the one he his part of. It seems relationship is the trick but somehow I can't make it work .

So far I tried in Relationship:

```
 OG membership: OG membership from Node group 

(OG membership from node group) OG membership: User from OG    membership
```

and to add in contextual filter:

```
(user from OG membership) User: Uid (with default value set to "user id from logged in user")
```

But it doesn't seem to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `OG membership: Group ID` as a contextual filter,
click `Provide Default: The OG groups of the logged in user`
and under `More` at the bottom of the filter's settings,
click `Allow multiple values`.